# How do I get proportions in data table without group number repeating?

Tags: r, data.table

Following obtaining a correlation matrix, I want to get the variables whereby the abs(coefficient) is greater than 0.6 in more than 50% of the data points.

I have gone about this in certain steps using both dplyr and data table.

```
resfull3 <- data.frame(
  rho = c(
    "-0.910801310862479", "-0.908882363736465", "-0.894664645749963",
    "0.651455464648868", "-0.886422033270298", "0.466935754868337",
    "-0.910801310862479", "0.927651578541531", "0.901790935170842",
    "-0.678881187019605", "0.857728162220158", "-0.572350948079171",
    "-0.908882363736465", "0.927651578541531", "0.851042626992907",
    "-0.683592097859172", "0.89770643712998", "-0.459781759802587",
    "-0.894664645749963", "0.901790935170842", "0.851042626992907",
    "-0.520124985810847", "0.774676733391384", "-0.66660602135505",
    "0.651455464648868", "-0.678881187019605", "-0.683592097859172",
    "-0.520124985810847", "-0.750390414939875", "0.0918686313382548",
    "-0.886422033270298", "0.857728162220158", "0.89770643712998",
    "0.774676733391384", "-0.750390414939875", "-0.225401200643088",
    "0.466935754868337", "-0.572350948079171", "-0.459781759802587",
    "-0.66660602135505", "0.0918686313382548", "-0.225401200643088"
  ),
  V2 = rep(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec"), each = 6L),
  V3 = c(
    "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "mpg", "disp", "hp",
    "drat", "wt", "qsec", "mpg", "cyl", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec",
    "mpg", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "mpg", "cyl", "disp",
    "hp", "wt", "qsec", "mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "qsec",
    "mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt"
  )
)
```

1-add another column with logical TRUE/FALSE if coefficient exceeds threshold,
2- add a grp variable,
3- summarise by selecting the proportion of TRUE,
4-select the grp with proportion exceed 0.5

##dplyr

```
 resfull4 <- mutate(resfull3, thresh=ifelse(rho >=0.6, "TRUE", "FALSE"))
 resfull4$thresh <-  as.logical(resfull4$thresh)
 resfull5 <- mutate(resfull4, grp=rep(1:(n()/6), each=6, length.out=n()))
 resy <- resfull5 %>%  group_by(grp) %>% summarize(prop=sum(thresh == "TRUE")/n()) 
 out <- filter(resy, prop >=0.5)
```

##data table

```
 resfull3a <- setDT(resfull3)
 resfull4a <- resfull3a[, "Thresh" := ifelse(rho >=0.6, "TRUE", "FALSE")]
 resfull4a$Thresh <-  as.logical(resfull4a$Thresh)
 resfully <- resfull4a[, grp:=rep(1:(.N/6), each=6, length.out=.N)]
 resfully2 <- resfully[, sum:= .N, by=grp]
 resfully3 <- resfully2[, .(prop = sum(Thresh== "TRUE")/sum), by=grp]
```

Its probably very inefficient; however, the output of resfully3 is a 42 x 2 table, when it should be 7 x 2 like with dplyr, just the grp 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and the proportions, not each grp number and proportion repeating 7 times. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) `rho` is a vector of strings, how do you intend to measure *"exceeds threshold"*? If your real data shows `class(resfull3$rho)` as `"numeric"`, then please give us an improved sample; if your real data is also strings in `rho`, then I suggest you fix whatever step in your process broke your data. (2) You corrupted the object when you removed `row.names=...` from the output of `dput`. Don't do that.

Comment: Don't use `ifelse` and string literals like that, it adds nothing except obscurity. Set `thresh=(rho >= 0.6)` the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(resfull3)[, thresh := rho >= 0.6
  ][, grp := 1 + ((.I - 1) %/% 6)
  ][, .(prop = mean(thresh)), by = .(grp)
  ][prop >= 0.5, ]
#      grp  prop
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     2   0.5
# 2:     3   0.5
# 3:     4   0.5
# 4:     6   0.5
```

1. Don't use `ifelse(rho >= 0.6, "TRUE", "FALSE")` and then `as.logical(.)`, that's juts double-trickery to get to the same thing. Just use `thresh = (rho >= 0.6)`, same results, faster, less code.
2. Similarly, you later to `thresh == "TRUE"` which then *re*-converts your `logical`-class to a string, completely unnecessary. Just use `thresh`. The `sum(thresh)` will return the number of instances where `thresh` is `TRUE` (note not a string).
3. Since you want the proportion (`sum(thresh)/.N`), this is equivalent to `mean(thresh)`. We *could* use `sum(thresh)/.N` if you want for the same results.
4. Bottom line, though: the reason that your `data.table` code did not *summarize* as you wanted: your `sum` *variable* is length `.N` for each group, so `sum(thresh)` produces length-1 for each group by your `sum` variable is length `.N`, so the output from that ratio will be length `.N`.

   My head hurts ... let me change your `sum` *variable* to `some` for clarity:

   ```r
    resfully2 <- resfully[, some := .N, by=grp]
    resfully3 <- resfully2[, .(prop = sum(Thresh== "TRUE")/some), by=grp]
   ```

   In the first line, `some` will be the same number for all rows within a group. In the second line, `sum(Thresh == "TRUE")` (sic) resolves to a length-1 number which is correct, but since you divide that by length-n `some`, you get the length-n result (same ratio repeated). Had you instead done

   ```r
    resfully3 <- resfully2[, .(prop = sum(Thresh== "TRUE")/some[1]), by=grp]
   ```

   you would have seen better results.

   ```r
    resfully2 <- resfully[, some:= .N, by=grp]
    resfully3 <- resfully2[, .(prop = sum(Thresh== "TRUE")/some[1]), by=grp]
    resfully3[prop >= 0.5,]
   #      grp  prop
   #    <int> <num>
   # 1:     2   0.5
   # 2:     3   0.5
   # 3:     4   0.5
   # 4:     6   0.5
   ```

Comment: very helpful, thank you! Would you recommend any particular resources to become more efficient at using data.table?

Comment: Nothing cosmic, mostly https://r-datatable.com/ and the github wiki https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki. (And trial-and-error, a method I found works well for me.)